# Yaml file for docker-compose traefik .yml can't find expected key

Tags: docker, traefik

So I've been following this guide:
https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/traefik-2-docker-tutorial/#Setting_Up_Environmental_Variables_for_Docker_and_Docker_Compose
To get my home server set up with a domain,using traefik 2.
I'm extremely new to all of this,Linux included so I'm relying heavily on writers knowledge of the process but I just can't get past the first test run of my docker compose yaml file for traefik 2. Been following up till now but when I attempt to run the docker container for traefik I get the error that yaml: line 49: did not find expected key
This looks to be the last line of the certificate resolver section, but I'm not sure what "key" it's expecting to find. So confused ‍

```
version: "3.8"

########################### NETWORKS
networks:
  t2_proxy:
    external:
      name: t2_proxy
  default:
    driver: bridge

########################### SERVICES
services:
# All services / apps go below this line
# Traefik 2 - Reverse Proxy
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik:2.6.1 # the chevrotin tag refers to v2.2.x but introduced a breaking change in 2.2.2
    restart: unless-stopped
command: # CLI arguments
      - --global.checkNewVersion=true
      - --global.sendAnonymousUsage=true
      - --entryPoints.http.address=:80
      - --entryPoints.https.address=:443
        # Allow these IPs to set the X-Forwarded-* headers - Cloudflare IPs: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/
      - --entrypoints.https.forwardedHeaders.trustedIPs=173.245.48.0/20,103.21.244.0/22,103.22.200.0/22,103.31.4.0/22,141.101.64.0/18,108.162.192.0/18,190.93.240.0/20,188.114.96.0/20,197.234.240.0/22,198.41.128.0/17,162.158.0.0/15,104.16.0.0/12,172.64.0.0/13,131.0.72.0/22
      - --entryPoints.traefik.address=:8080
      - --api=true
#      - --api.insecure=true
#      - --serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true
      - --log=true
      - --log.level=DEBUG # (Default: error) DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
      - --accessLog=true
      - --accessLog.filePath=/traefik.log
      - --accessLog.bufferingSize=100 # Configuring a buffer of 100 lines
      - --accessLog.filters.statusCodes=400-499
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - --providers.docker.defaultrule=Host(`{{ index .Labels "com.docker.compose.service" }}.$DOMAINNAME`)
      - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=t2_proxy
      - --providers.docker.swarmMode=false
      - --providers.file.directory=/rules # Load dynamic configuration from one or more .toml or .yml files in a directory.
#      - --providers.file.filename=/path/to/file # Load dynamic configuration from a file.
      - --providers.file.watch=true # Only works on top level files in the rules folder - 
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.caServer=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory # LetsEncrypt Staging Server - uncomment when testing - 
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.email=$CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL - 
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.storage=/acme.json - 
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.dnsChallenge.provider=cloudflare
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.dnsChallenge.resolvers=1.1.1.1:53,1.0.0.1:53
   networks:
#      t2_proxy:
#        ipv4_address: 192.168.90.829 # You can specify a static IP
    networks:
      - t2_proxy
 security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
 ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
 volumes:
      - $DOCKERDIR/traefik2/rules:/rules 
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - $DOCKERDIR/traefik2/acme/acme.json:/acme.json 
      - $DOCKERDIR/traefik2/traefik.log:/traefik.log 
      - $DOCKERDIR/shared:/shared
environment:
      - CF_API_EMAIL=$CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL
      - CF_API_KEY=$CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY
labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # HTTP-to-HTTPS Redirect
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=HostRegexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
   # HTTP Routers
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.rule=Host(`traefik.$DOMAINNAME`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.certresolver=dns-cloudflare" # Comment out this line after first run of traefik to force the use of wildcard certs
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[0].main=$DOMAINNAME"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[0].sans=*.$DOMAINNAME"
#      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[1].main=$SECONDDOMAINNAME" # Pulls main cert for second domain
#      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[1].sans=*.$SECONDDOMAINNAME" # Pulls wildcard cert for second domain
## Services - API
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.service=api@internal"
      ## Middlewares
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.middlewares=middlewares-basic-auth@file"
```

The tree output:

├── ./docker-compose-t2.yml

├── ./docker-compose-t2.yml.save

├── ./.env

├── ./.env.save

├── ./.env.save.1

├── ./output

├── ./output.txt

├── ./shared

│   └── ./shared/.htpasswd

├── ./traefik2

│   ├── ./traefik2/acme

│   │   └── ./traefik2/acme/acme.json

│   ├── ./traefik2/rules

│   │   └── ./traefik2/rules/middlewares.toml

│   └── ./traefik2/traefik.log

└── ./tree.txt

Comment: The yml file is stored in the main docker folder @ /home/user/docker
And the run command the guide gives is: docker-compose -f docker-compose-t2.yml up -d

Comment: Show us tree . output.

Comment: ``` 4 directories, 7 files
bradley@NASpc:~/docker$ tree -a
.

Comment: I added the tree output as best I could up above
Also, looks like I might be dealing with some systemic formatting issues? I moved all the tabs under cli arguments in two spaces, but then that just moved the expected key error down several lines

Comment: All of the options underneath `traefik:` (`image:`, `restart:`, `command:`, `networks:`, `ports:`, `volumes:`, `environment:`, `labels:`) need to have the same indentation, in the file as you've shown it probably exactly four spaces.  Is this correct in the file you have locally?

Comment: @BradMartin Yeah,brad is right fix the indentation.

Comment: @DavidMaze yup, that got it running, but now I can't access the traefik dashboard